# Mindtouch with fcgid - Fast CGI apache worker thread

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-fcgid, dekiwiki

Anyone got Dekiwiki / Mindtouch running with fcgid-module? I get 504 and 500 all the time.

```
 mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/html/dekiwiki/index.php
[Tue Dec 28 06:14:03 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Tue Dec 28 06:14:03 2010] [error] [client 92.75.107.53] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

I'm currently fiddling with SuExec and fast-cgi wrapper directory permissions, because I also employ a chrooted SFTP jail. Sometimes the first line about the process slot does not appear now.

I found a solution in german and will work it through now.

http://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=122758&start=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter in httpd.conf: `LogLevel debug`

It will work wonders for your `/var/log/httpd/error_log` file.

The rest is permissions, rewrite rules and understanding suexec (see apache docs)

Also pay attention to your `php-fcgi-starter` file settings. You have to export the `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` variable.

```
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
```

Also see here *(http://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=78073&start=105)* [german]

This are the final configurations that worked for me:

php-fcgi-starter:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PHPRC=/etc/
#export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=50
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Make sure your `dekiwiki-apache.conf` is tidy and neatly nested. Enable any modules in `httpd.conf` for required options like `ProxyPassReverse`.

Make sure to nest the rewrite rules into the `<Directory /var/www/html/yourwikiname>` directive. Set `AllowOverride All`, make sure it isn't unset anywhere for that directory.

Another 'peace of the puzzle' that helped me was to use the latest mod_rewrite rules from mindtouch via SVN.

It's also important to set these values in `httpd.conf` according to the `/usr/sbin/suexec` owners.

```
User apache
Group chrootJailGroup
```

Don't forget if you change suexec's owners you have to set the suid again.

```
ls -lisha /usr/sbin/suexec 
-r-s--x--- 1 root chrootJailGroup 14K Aug 30 18:32 /usr/sbin/suexec
```